# Probability of ordered dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you throw five dice, order them from lowest to highest number, then select the third die. What is the probability that the third die was number 2?

Or, in general, when throwing $n$ dice and selecting the $i$th die (sorted from low to high), what is the probability that the number of that die is $k_i$? So the above example was $n=5,i=3,k_i=2$. How do you determine a general formula for finding the probability?

Comment: In R you can use `pbeta(k_i/6, i, n-i+1) - pbeta((k_i-1)/6, i, n+1-i)` which with $n=5,i=3,k_i=2$ would give about $0.1743827$

Comment: Does that generalize to multiple selections? In other words, with $n = 5$, what are the odds that $i = 3, k_i = 2$ **_and_** $j =4, k_j = 2$? (Obviously, where $j > i$, $k_j >= k_i$ for any sorted roll.)

Comment: Also, what if the dice are not "fair"? For example, consider a six-sided die with the faces $(2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)$. I'm assuming that translates to:

$\text{pbeta}(k_i  \times P(k_i), i, n - i + 1) - \text{pbeta}((k_i - 1) \times P(k_i), i, n - i + 1)$.

Is that right?

Comment: Forgive my hijacking this comment thread for my own purposes. I have asked my question(s) separately here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173084/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a die with $q$  faces that we roll $n$ times, sort the
outcomes, and ask about the probability  that the value $k$ appears at
position $p.$ We thus have the marked combinatorial class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=k-1}(\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\mathcal{Z})) \times
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{V}\mathcal{Z}) \times
\textsc{SEQ}_{=q-k}(\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This yields the mixed EGF

$$G(z, u, v) = \exp((k-1)uz) \exp(vz) \exp((q-k)z).$$

With $r$ the number of values less than $k$ we obtain from coefficient
extraction

$$\sum_{r=0}^{p-1} [u^r] \exp((k-1)uz) \exp(vz) \exp((q-k)z)
\\ = \sum_{r=0}^{p-1} 
\frac{1}{r!} (k-1)^r z^r \exp(vz) \exp((q-k)z).$$

We must have at least $p-r$ instances of the value $k$ which yields

$$\sum_{r=0}^{p-1} 
\frac{1}{r!} (k-1)^r z^r 
\sum_{j\ge p-r} \frac{z^j}{j!}
\exp((q-k)z).$$

With $n$ rolls of the die we get

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{r=0}^{p-1} 
\frac{1}{r!} (k-1)^r 
\sum_{j\ge p-r} \frac{z^{j+r}}{j!}
\exp((q-k)z)
\\ = n! \sum_{r=0}^{p-1} 
\frac{1}{r!} (k-1)^r 
\sum_{j\ge p-r} \frac{1}{j!}
[z^{n-j-r}] \exp((q-k)z).$$

We must have $n-j-r\ge 0$ or $n-r\ge j$ so we obtain

$$n! \sum_{r=0}^{p-1} 
\frac{1}{r!} (k-1)^r 
\sum_{j=p-r}^{n-r} \frac{1}{j!}
[z^{n-j-r}] \exp((q-k)z)
\\ = n! \sum_{r=0}^{p-1} 
\frac{1}{r!} (k-1)^r 
\sum_{j=p-r}^{n-r} \frac{1}{j!}
\frac{(q-k)^{n-j-r}}{(n-j-r)!}.$$

This yields for the probability

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{q^n} 
\sum_{r=0}^{p-1} 
{n\choose r} (k-1)^r 
\sum_{j=p-r}^{n-r} {n-r\choose j}
(q-k)^{n-j-r}.}$$

The following  Maple code was used  to verify this formula.  There are
two enumeration routines, one from the problem statement and the other
one incorporating some optimization. The closed formula is implemented
as well and the output matched on all cases that were examined.

```
with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(q, n, p, k)
option remember;
local ind, rolls, res;

    res := 0;

    for ind from q^n to 2*q^n-1 do
        rolls := convert(ind, base, q);
        rolls := sort(rolls[1..n]);

        if rolls[p] = k-1 then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res/q^n;
end;

ENUM2 :=
proc(q, n, p, k)
option remember;
local res, part, psize, vals, ordpart, rolls;

    res := 0;

    part := firstpart(n);

    while type(part, list) do
        psize := nops(part);

        for vals in choose(q, psize) do
            for ordpart in permute(part) do
                rolls :=
                [seq(vals[blk]$ordpart[blk],
                     blk=1..psize)];

                if rolls[p] = k then
                    res := res +
                    n!/mul(it!, it in ordpart);
                fi;
            od;
        od;

        part := nextpart(part);
    od;

    res/q^n;
end;


X := (q, n, p, k) ->
1/q^n*add(binomial(n, r)*(k-1)^r*
          add(binomial(n-r, j)*(q-k)^(n-j-r),
              j=p-r..n-r), r=0..p-1);
```

Comment: Clear and concise. Very nice. (+1)

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I did not think at first that there would be such a compact closed form.

Comment: Does this have a similarly nice form if we allow the dice to have varying ranges? for example 1 to 6, 1 to 8, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the multinomial law to compute this probability. If we split the probability on the number of 2 you draw we have

$$p=\mathbb P(\textrm{exactly one 2 and two 1}) + \mathbb P(\textrm{exactly two 2 and (one or two) 1}) + \mathbb P(\textrm{exactly three 2}) + \mathbb P(\textrm{exactly four 2}) + \mathbb P(\textrm{exactly five 2})$$

$$p=\left(5 \cdot 6 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)\left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)^2\left( \dfrac{4}{6} \right)^2 \right) + \left(10 \cdot 3 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)^2\left(\left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)^2\left( \dfrac{4}{6} \right)+\left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)\left( \dfrac{4}{6} \right)^2 \right) \right) + \left(10 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)^3\left( \dfrac{5}{6} \right)^2 \right) + \left( 5\left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)^4\left( \dfrac{5}{6} \right)\right) + \left( \left( \dfrac{1}{6} \right)^5\right)$$

$$p=\left( \dfrac{30 \cdot 16}{6^5}\right) + \left( \dfrac{30 \cdot 20}{6^5}\right) + \left( \dfrac{10 \cdot 25}{6^5}\right) + \left( \dfrac{5 \cdot 5}{6^5}\right)+\left( \dfrac{1}{6^5}\right)$$

$$p=\dfrac{1356}{6^5} \approx 0.17438$$

And we get the probability that @Henry found with R. We can also verify it with a simple Python program that gives the same result

```
from random import randint

ok = 0
nb_draws = 100000
for j in range(nb_draws):
    l = [randint(1,6) for i in range(5)]
    l.sort()
    if l[2] == 2:
        ok += 1

print(ok * 1.0 / nb_draws)
```

Comment: $\dfrac{100}{6^5}\approx 0.01286$ looks very low

Comment: Die is singular, dice is plural, and dices means to cut into small cubes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks a lot is is corrected :)

Comment: @Henry you're correct I computed the proba in a sequential (and wrong) manner. I corrected the computations and I obtain the same result as you

Comment: I obtained the same probability. Upvote (+1) to first responder.

Answer (score 0):

A simple general way of solving this is via order statistics. In particular, let  $X \sim \text{DiscreteUniform}(1,6)$ represent our die with pmf $f(x)$:

[image]

Given a sample of size $n$ drawn on parent $X$, the pmf of the $i^{\text{th}}$ ordered variable (order statistic) $X_{(i)}$, denoted $g(x)$, is:

[image]

where I am using the `OrderStat` function from *mathStatica*/*Mathematica* to automate the nitty-gritties, and where `Beta[x,a,b]` denotes the incomplete Beta function $\int _0^x t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} dt$. This is the general solution that you seek. For instance, in the specific case provided, with $n = 5$, $i = 3$, and $x = 2$, the exact $P(X_{(3)}=2)$ is:

[image]

... which is $\approx$ 0.174383. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors of the software used above.

Comment: I'm curious whether this can be generalized to multiple selections: math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173084