# Probability distribution of $k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_m$ selections of arbitrary positions from sorted rolls when rolling $n$ dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

*Question edited in response to comments, primarily for clarity and for avoiding the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Apologies in advance if this is in-artfully asked. I am trying to teach myself discrete probabilities and still have a lot to learn.*

I am trying to figure out a way to more efficiently compute probability distributions when making $k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_m$ arbitrary selections (but where $k_1 > k_2 > \cdots > k_m$) among sorted rolls from $n$ dice. For now, let’s assume I mean fair six-sided dice. For example, when rolling 4 dice ($n = 4$), I might want to select the 2nd and 4th positions ($k_1 = 2, k_2 = 4$) from the sorted result:

```
            ┌─╼ n = 4 dice
   ┌─────┬──┴──┬─────┐
┌─────┲━━━━━┱─────┲━━━━━┓
│  1  ┃  1  ┃  1  ┃  1  ┃
├─────╊━━━━━╉─────╊━━━━━┫
│  1  ┃  1  ┃  1  ┃  2  ┃
├─────╊━━━━━╉─────╊━━━━━┫
│  …  ┃  …  ┃  …  ┃  …  ┃
├─────╊━━━━━╉─────╊━━━━━┫
│  5  ┃  6  ┃  6  ┃  6  ┃┐
├─────╊━━━━━╉─────╊━━━━━┫├─╼ these both contribute (6, 6)
│  6  ┃  6  ┃  6  ┃  6  ┃┘
└─────┺━━━━━┹─────┺━━━━━┛
         └─────┬─────┘
               └─╼ selecting for k₁ = 2 and k₂ = 4
```

This comes up in various game mechanics.

There are a couple ways I currently know how to approach this, but I want to do better (computationally), because the methods of which I am aware become very expensive, very quickly.

The brute force (but straightforward) way is to enumerate the Cartesian product of the dice, sort each result, select $k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_m$ from that result, then count how many times that selection appears.

```
# brute_force.py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product
from typing import Counter as CounterT, Sequence

def brute_force(
    n: int,
    selections: Sequence[int],
    d: Sequence[int] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),  # default to fair, six-sided die
):
    counts_by_roll: CounterT[int] = Counter()
    for roll in product(*(d for _ in range(n))):
        sorted_roll = sorted(roll)
        roll_after_selections = tuple(sorted_roll[i] for i in selections)
        counts_by_roll[roll_after_selections] += 1
    return counts_by_roll

assert brute_force(4, (1, 3)) == {  # Python indexing is zero-based
  (1,1):  1, (1,2):  10, (1,3):  22, (1,4):  34, (1,5):  46, (1,6):  58,
             (2,2):   5, (2,3):  34, (2,4):  70, (2,5): 106, (2,6): 142,
                         (3,3):   9, (3,4):  58, (3,5): 118, (3,6): 178,
                                     (4,4):  13, (4,5):  82, (4,6): 166,
                                                 (5,5):  17, (5,6): 106,
                                                             (6,6):  21,
}
```

There are certainly improvements to be had (like leveraging the multinomial coefficient to limit enumerations to combinations with replacement, as well as some special case optimizations where the selections are near one end), but so far, every approach I know scales exponentially with $n$ in the general case. I’d like to see if I can get something that will scale closer to $m$, regardless of where $k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_m$ fall in $\left [ 1..n \right ]$.

I *thought* I could break this problem down into sub problems by observing that, for any particular sorted roll, the values between selections must fall into a range bounded by the values at those selections. That is turning out to be difficult.

I have read “[Calculating the probability of getting a specific set of dice from a single roll](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871623/)” and “[Probability of ordered dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319030/probability-of-ordered-dice)” and attempted to wade through their answers.

Where $m = 1$, I can use the beta function outlined in [this response to the second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2320938/226394), but I don’t know if or how I can generalize for $m > 1$.

---

*UPDATE:* In pursuing my example further, if I enumerate distributions (using computationally expensive methods) for $n = 4$, $k_1 = 2$, $k_2 = 4$, I can construct the following table, where the columns correlate to the die face appearing in position $k_1$ and the rows correlate to the die face appearing in position $k_2$:

| **$k_2=4$ ☞ ☟ $k_1=2$** | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | *5* | 6 | Sum (Beta) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 10 | 22 | 34 | *46* | 58 | 171 |
| **2** | 0 | 5 | 34 | 70 | *106* | 142 | 357 |
| ***3*** | *0* | *0* | *9* | *58* | ***118*** | *178* | *363* |
| **4** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | *82* | 166 | 261 |
| **5** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *17* | 106 | 123 |
| **6** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *0* | 21 | 21 |
| **Sum (Beta)** | 1 | 15 | 65 | 175 | *369* | 671 | 1,296 |

The ***highlighted*** cell indicates the total number of times (118 out of 1,296 total) where a three appears in position 2 ***and*** a five appears in position 4. I observe that the sum of each column is the beta probability for that face appearing in $k_1$ and the sum of each row is the beta probability for that face appearing in $k_2$, which makes sense.

I don’t yet know whether this is useful. Calculating the betas is cheap. I don’t know whether I can leverage them to calculate all values in the table. There are cells which we can trivially populate, however, such as where the faces at $k_1$ and $k_2$ are equal, and zero wherever the face at $k_2$ is less than the face at $k_1$ (since, by definition, that can’t happen for sorted rolls). But there are 21 interior values ($6 + 5 … + 2 + 1$) and only 12 ($6 + 6$) equations (13, if you count summing all the interior values), which doesn’t seem like enough unless some other relationship is present that I just don’t see or appreciate.

Comment: The secret to simple expressions is symmetry.  When you have different restrictions on the dice like this, you often get stuck just counting all the possibilities.

Comment: 1) The fact that "no two constraints will ever implicate the same die" is difficult to treat and generalize to $n$ dice **knowing that the fourth constraint involves 2 dice** (isn't it contradictory ?). 2) Moreover, could you say why you are interested in this particular situation ? Is it for modellising a game ? 3) The theoretical tool you could consider is inclusion-exclusion formula (but very complicated for practical means)

Comment: @JeanMarie, unless I mistyped, there shouldn't be a fourth constraint. There's a third that covers two dice. If helpful, you could think of it (sort of) as four separate constraints:

 1. A first die shows $[1‥3]$.
 2. A second die shows $[3‥3]$.
 3. A third die shows $[3‥6]$.
 4. A fourth die shows $[3‥6]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie, how would one model this with inclusion-exclusion? Also, if I understand correctly, the number of computations required for inclusion-exclusion is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}$, which works out to $2^{n} -1$, no? For $n = 10$, that would be 1,023 separate computations.

Comment: For your second remark. Yes, and this is the problem... Such calculations are no longer for humans...

Comment: For your first remark: I have noted "The probability of" was used four times, and I was mentionning the fourth one. But more generaly 1) It is difficult to see where your conditions are connected by an "and" vs an (exclusive) "or" ; and you know this is basic in probability 2) I think that the problem you submit to our attention lacks a final goal. It looks artificial. Why are you interest at this question ? 3) Having taught probabilities at undergraduate level, may I advise you to solve problems involving classical Bernoulli, binomial, geometric, Poisson, Pascal laws (for the discrete laws).

Comment: Thanks for your continued attention, @JeanMarie. I have edited the question in response to your feedback.